# Passing self to function within initialization of object in python

Tags: python, class, tree, initialization

I have a class which represents a node of a tree-like structure which stores it's parent node and any children nodes

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,n, p):
        self.name = n
        self.parent = p
        self.children = []
        if p != None:       
            p.addChild(self)

    def setParent(np):
        if np != None:
            self.parent = np


    def addChild(nc):
        if nc != None:
            children.append(nc)
```

For automation purposes, when the node's created, I want it to call the `addChild` method of the parent node to add itself to the children list, but as is when a node is initialized with a parent in this manner, I get the error:
`TypeError: addChild() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

How is it getting 2 arguments from `self`? Perhaps there is a more logical way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

```
p.addChild(self)
```

Python will make a call to `addChild` like this

```
addChild(p, self)
```

because `addChild` and `setParent` are instance methods. So, they need to accept the current object on which they are invoked as the first parameter,

```
def setParent(self, np):
    ...
def addChild(self, np):
    ...
    self.children.append(nc)    # You meant the children of the current instance
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `self` the first argument of class methods.

```
def setParent(self, np)

def addChild(self, nc)
```

You should also definitely read this: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html